# RXJS: throttleTime plus last value

Tags: rxjs

I have a scenario where a lot of events can be sent to a stream in a short amount of time. I would like to have an operator that is kind of a mixture of `debounceTime` and `throttleTime`.

The following demo can be used to illustrate what I would like to have, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-jxbght?file=index.ts.
I would like the subscriber to get the first emitted event and THEN wait for x ms. If more events were emitted during the waiting time, the last event should be sent to the subscriber after the waiting time. The waiting time should be reset on each new emitted event, just like debounce do.

If you click on the button 3 times within 1 second it should print 1 and 3. If you then click only 1 time within 1 second it should print only 4. If you then click 3 times again it should print 5 and 7.

This does not work with `debounceTime` since that doesn't give me the first event and it doesn't work for `throttleTime` because that doesn't give me the last emitted value after the wait time is over.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

**UPDATE**

I created a custom operator with the help from Martins's answer. Not sure if it is working 100% correctly or if there are better ways to do it but it seems to do what I want it to.

```
import { Observable, empty } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, timeoutWith, debounceTime, take, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function takeFirstThenDebounceTime(waitTime) {
    return function takeFirstThenDebounceTimeImplementation(source) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber => {
            const subscription = source.
                pipe(
                    exhaustMap(val => source.pipe(
                        timeoutWith(waitTime, empty()),
                        debounceTime(waitTime),
                        take(1),
                        startWith(val)
                    )),
                )
                .subscribe(value => {
                    subscriber.next(value);
                },
                    err => subscriber.error(err),
                    () => subscriber.complete());

            return subscription;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In RxJS 6 there are some additional options for the `throttleTime` operator that are undocumented right now and where you can make it to emit at both  start and end of the duration. So maybe this could help you.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/throttleTime.ts#L55

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/throttle.ts#L12

However, since you want to reset the timeout on every emission it'll be more complicated. This should be simplified example with random emits but I wonder if there's an easier way to do it:

```
const shared = source.pipe(shareReplay(1))

shared
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(val => shared.pipe(
      timeout(1000),
      catchError(() => empty()),
      debounceTime(1000),
      take(1),
      startWith(val),
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

This demo debounces after 175ms gap. I hope it makes sense to you.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-ztppwy?file=index.ts

Comment: I'm not sure if your example works as I want. I updated my question and modified your demo a bit, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-v9xzl1?file=index.ts. If you click on the button multiple times, I would like the first click to emit and then when there has not been a click for 1000 ms it should emit again. Then when the user clicks again, it should directly emit and then if the button is clicked within 1000ms it should wait until 1000ms has passed and then emit.

Comment: Aha, then you can just rearrange the operators and and use `shareReplay(1)` instead, see updated demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-okg8cs?file=index.ts

Comment: almost there :) The only thing left is that I don't want it to emit in the end of the waiting time if there was no second click.

Comment: I think I found a solution but it's starting to get nasty, so maybe you could put this login into a custom operator instead. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-ztppwy?file=index.ts

Comment: Seems to be working as I wanted now, thanks! Many operators I have never used before so I need to read a little bit more about them and then I will try to put it in a custom operator :)

Answer (score 10):

This operator should give you the first value, the throttled stream and the last value:

```js
export function throunceTime<T>(duration: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    merge(source.pipe(throttleTime(duration)), source.pipe(debounceTime(duration)))
      .pipe(throttleTime(0, undefined, { leading: true, trailing: false }));
}
```

Comment: hi mate your approach is just awesome! I have problem with it though when trying to use for my my similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975685/get-one-event-per-1000-milliseconds-interval . I tried your operator - looks short and brilliant but with 3 groups of 9 events when last event will pass both `debounceTime` and `throttleTime` I'll get duplicated event `#9`. do you have any ideas how to fix this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-take-once-per-second-throuncetime?file=index.ts

Comment: @godblessstrawberry I tried your stackblitz and it worked as intended for me. Did not get #9 twice. Though I guess this can happen on some millisecond jittering in the end.

Comment: can you try again please? I just edited and saved - its works okay for `take(10)` and for `take(9)` it doubles the last event - one is coming from throttle and one more from debounce. I can do `distinctUntilChanged(deepEqual)` but its to heavy for the objects I plan to distinct(

Comment: Yes I can see that it happens. For me it was only important to really have first and last values, having the last one twice was not a problem in my use case. You'll have to come up with another solution I guess.

Comment: I got some wonkey websocket sending messages and this is perfect

Answer (score 1):

you probably don't need a custom operator if you use the `trailing` and `leading` config:

```
throttleTime(500, undefined, { leading: true, trailing: true })
```