# Get one event per 1000 milliseconds interval

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I have infinite stream of events that can emit some consecutive event portions and I want to take one event per 1000 each milliseconds.

I tried `debounceTime` / `auditTime` / `throttleTime` but they doesn't include all events I want - to demonstrate the behavior I created [playground on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9elogc?devtoolsheight=60) which fires events once per 300ms within portion of 10 events:

- `debounceTime(1000)` will give only event #`10`
- `throttleTime(1000)` will give events `1,5,9` but it will omit #`10`
  which is essential
- `auditTime(1000)` will give events `4,8`

What I want here is to get events `1,5,9,10` (one event per 1000ms interval). How do I achieve this?

```js
const events$ = interval(300).pipe(
  map(num => `Firing event ${num + 1}`)
);

const source = events$.pipe(
  tap(console.log),
  take(10),
  // make some debouncing??
  map(x => `Received ${x}!`)
);

source.subscribe(x =>
  console.log(
    "%c" + x,
    "background: purple; color: white; padding: 3px 5px; border-radius: 3px;"
  )
);
```

I also tried to play with `zip` / `combineLatest` and emitting values via interval [but no luck with that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2vktb5?file=index.ts)

Comment: could you explain what you mean with the including last one? you want to get it like current value after 1000ms and last known value? so it would be a chain of history of 1, is it correct?

Comment: I want to emit no more then 1 event per 1000 ms, throttle now will omit #10 as it goes too soon after #9 - I want it to fire #10 as its the only event per last 1000ms interval

Comment: then how should it bring 10? 1 is in by default, 2/300 out, 3/600 out, 4/900 out, 5/1200 in, 6/300 out, 7/600 out, 8/900 out, 9/1200 in, 10/300 - out. Or do you want to count it as 1/0 in, 2/300 out, 3/600 out, 4/900 out, /1000 reset, 5/200 in, 6/500 out, 7/800 out, 1000/ reset, 8/100 in, 9/400 out, 10/700 out... doesn't work too.

Comment: if you want 10 just because it's 10th and you expect group of 10 emits - let me know.

Comment: ok got your point, I'm not expecting exactly 10 - I expect group of events and if throttle them I might lose last events which are important. So if no more events coming after latest that goes in current 1000ms interval - it should be streamed. I thought about combining streams via `merge(events$.throttleTime(1000), events$.debounceTime(1000)` but I'm not sure this will cover all cases

Comment: aha, got your point. good. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: added the answer, once there's a delay more than 1000 the last value will be emitted to the stream, if it wasn't before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

based on the discussion in comments

```js
const events$ = timer(0, 6000).pipe(
  take(3),
  switchMap(x =>
    timer(0, 300).pipe(
      map(num => `event #${num + 1}`),
      take(x > 1 ? 9 : 10)
    )
  )
);

const source = merge(
  events$.pipe(
    tap(e => console.log(`%cStream: ${e}`, "color: blue;")),
    debounceTime(1000),
    tap(x => console.log(`%cdebounceTime captured: ${x}`, "color: red;"))
  ),
  events$.pipe(
    throttleTime(1000),
    tap(x => console.log(`%cthrottleTime captured: ${x}`, "color: green;"))
  ),
).pipe(
  // we need to avoid duplicates (like case with 9).
  // if all events aren't unique you need to use the original solution below.
  distinctUntilChanged(), // <-- if all events are unique.
  map(x => `Received ${x}!`)
);

source.subscribe(x =>
  console.log(
    "%c" + x,
    "background: purple; color: white; padding: 3px 5px; border-radius: 3px;"
  )
);
```

**ORIGINAL**

I hope that's what you wanted: https://take.ms/VP7tA

```js
const events$ = interval(300).pipe(
    map(num => `Firing event ${num + 1}`)
);

const source = concat(events$.pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    take(10),
), timer(1000).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY)), events$.pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    take(10),
));

let lastTimer = 0;
const last$ = new Subject<number>();
merge(
    source.pipe(
      scan((state, event) => {
        state[1] = null;
        const stamp = new Date().getTime();
        clearTimeout(lastTimer);
        if (stamp - state[0] < 1000) {
          lastTimer = setTimeout(() => last$.next(event), (stamp - state[0]) + 50);
          return state;
        }
        state[0] = stamp;
        state[1] = event;
        return state;
      }, [0, null]),
      filter(([, event]) => event !== null),
      map(([, event]) => event || 0),
    ),
    last$,
).pipe(
    map(x => `Received ${JSON.stringify(x)}!`)
).subscribe(x =>
    console.log(
        "%c" + x,
        "background: purple; color: white; padding: 3px 5px; border-radius: 3px;"
    )
);
```

Comment: dude this works just awesome, but isn't it overcomplicated? what do you think about simultaneous usage of 2 streams - any pitfalls with my solution? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-take-once-per-second?file=index.ts

Comment: I wouldn't say it is overcomplicated. I would say it is not polished :) definitely would make sense to write an own rx operator and to put this logic inside of it, something like `throttleWithLast(1000)`. But for that I would need more time, you know. The thing you need to keep in mind is that `last$` doesn't complete, you need to handle it somehwere if you don't want to implement `throttleWithLast`. In code you have - reduce amount of the `take` to `take(9)`. Then you get 9th event 2 times. Besides that it looks much better than mine :)

Comment: Looks like `distinctUntilChanged` can do the job with 9. I've updated response based on your solution, if it's fine.

Comment: yeah this would work like a charm for simple values - what I have is huge `source$` object that represents whole application state and I need to pass full update to subscribers, I'm unable to compare them easily - I cannot rely on some `state$.prop` via `distinctUntilChanged((prevState, nextState) => prevState.prop === nextState.prop)` as any of them can change - only `deepEqual` will help here but I believe this will significally slow down the app(

Comment: I see, then yes, if there're nested changes without root pointer shakes the original solution should be used, it respects the sequence and doesn't require deepEqual.

Comment: hey mate with nice nickname) what do you think about this approach? I put original data into object with unique `updateId` and then I will distinct this after both `debounced$` / `throttled$` streams by this `updateId` and map back to original data after? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-take-once-per-second-throuncetime-distincted?file=index.ts
in real life this might fire very often - once per few milliseconds but this seems to be very lightweight operation, what do you think?

Comment: Hi again :) it definitely makes sense and simplifies the implementation, once you have an easy way to distinguish data debounced$ / throttled$ / distinctUntilChanged will provide a straight forward and readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to this:

```js
const events$ = interval(300).pipe(
  map(num => `Firing event ${num + 1}`),
  share(),
);

const source$ = events$.pipe(
  take(10),
);

const lastValue$ = source$.pipe(last());

merge(source$.pipe(throttleTime(1000)), lastValue$).subscribe(console.log);
```

`share()` will make sure the source(the observable produced `interval` by) is subscribed only once

`last()` will return the latest *nexted* value when its source(`source$` in this case) completes due to `take(10)`

### EDIT

Based on my understanding of the problem, this would be another alternative:

```js
const events$ = merge(
  timer(300), // 1
  timer(600), // 2
  timer(900), // 3
  timer(1301), // 4
  timer(1500), // 5
  timer(1800), // 6
  timer(2302), // 7
).pipe(
  map((_, num) => `Firing event ${num + 1}`),
  share(),
);

const lastValue$ = events$.pipe(debounceTime(1000));

const source$ = events$.pipe(
  throttleTime(1000),
  buffer(lastValue$)
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```

- `debounceTime(1000)` - if 1s passed without any notifications
- `buffer(lastValue$)` - when `lastValue$` emits, send the collected values

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/include-last-throttle?file=index.ts)

Comment: sorry I was not presize - edited my question, the stream is infinite, 10 events is only example of events portion so I cant use `last()`. My endless stream gives portions of events - e.g. it gives 10 events with interval of 300ms, I need to throttle them with 1000ms but I also need last one in current portion and after that I will continue observing the stream

Comment: I think you could still use last(), because it would complete due to take(). Also because of take(n), when n emissions are reached, it will unsubscribe from the source, so if you still want to receive values, you could use bufferCount; I’ll update my answer

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Updated.

Comment: Wasting some good amount on time this it worth some feedback. I'd highly appreciate if I could get some explanation of what in my answer is wrong/misleading. Thanks.

Comment: mate I appreciate your answer and didnt downvote this, though your solution doesnt seem to be working - I tried here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-take-once-per-second-verbose-fkrapo?file=index.ts on 3 portions of 9 events - it omits last #9 and moreover it gives array of 3 events simultaneously - not when they actually fired